Adding vuetify to new clean nuxt installation gives me an error when running nuxt
I am new to nuxt and vuetify and I did a new fresh clean installation of nuxt. Then I followed the instructions on the the nuxt vuetify website to install vuetify-nuxt-module  https://nuxt.vuetifyjs.com/guide/ which command is npx nuxi@latest module add vuetify-nuxt-module
After adding the module I try and run nuxt by doing pnpm run dev but I get the following error:
Failed to resolve import "vuetify/iconsets/mdi" from "virtual:vuetify-icons-configuration"
If there is zero configuration necessary for the module as stated on the website and since this is a new clean installation why am I getting this error and how do I fix it please?

And alternative would be to use this installation process rather. Otherwise looks like you're missing some icons, feel free to either comment-out those or install them.

Feel free to post your own answer for people in the future that might have the same issue.

But now I get a warning in the console and it's because of the vuetify plugin:
[12:47:08]  WARN  The CJS build of Vite's Node API is deprecated. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#vite-cjs-node-api-deprecated for more details.

Change to ESM then.

How do I do that please?

Some of it is answered in the link provided above, the rest is a minor syntax difference that you can easily find online or ask any LLM to fix for you.

Have you tried to add Icon configuration in the nuxt.config.ts
check this link out: https://nuxt.vuetifyjs.com/guide/icons/ maybe it can help you to config icons in the vuetify
